# RSA with small encryption exponent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography, totient-function

In [RSA: Fast factorization of N if d and e are known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12328/rsa-fast-factorization-of-n-if-d-and-e-are-known) a comment under the OPs question stated that if the encrytion exponent $e$ is small compared to $N=p\cdot q$ for the RSA-primes $p,q$ (like $e<\sqrt{N}$) one could find $k$ in $de=1+k\varphi(N)$ by rounding $\frac{de}{N}$ as $k$ is an integer and $\varphi(N)\approx N$.

I don't know how to show this rigorously as I don't find a way to use $e<\sqrt{N}$ and I'm unsure whether the floor function or some other approximation was meant. (For the following i went with the floor as it seemed to be the most reasonable)

As $\varphi(N)\le N$ I know that:
$$k=\left\lfloor \frac{1}{N}+k\right\rfloor\ge\left\lfloor \frac{de}{N}\right\rfloor$$
As $\varphi(N)=N-p-q+1$ is also know that:
\begin{align*}
\left\lfloor\frac{de}{N}\right\rfloor&=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{N}+k\frac{\varphi(N)}{N}\right\rfloor\\
&=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{N}+k\frac{pq-p-q+1}{pq}\right\rfloor\\
&=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{N}+k\left(\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right\rfloor+k
\end{align*}
So it would be nice to have $\left\lfloor\frac{1}{N}+k\left(\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right\rfloor=0$ as this would show the preposition.

Does this result even hold true?

Comment: You use $n$ and $N$.  Are these two separate things or a typo?

Comment: Typo :) fixed it, thanks!

Comment: I think you've made an error in the last step, when pulling $k$ outside the floor function.  You left a 1 times $k$ that ought to be  $1/pq$ times $k$.

Comment: Yeah... hopefully that's the last transcription error.  Been working a while on maths today :P

Comment: I think this depends on how close $\varphi(n)$ is to $n$, which can vary quite a bit.  Like many crypto attacks, this one might be one that works with great success, but not 100%.

Comment: Oh ok, that's a possibility... I'm trying to factor $N=12051341$ given $e=5$ and $d=4817549$ by hand. The above would've allowed me to find $\varphi(N)$ and hence $p$ and $q$ with $N=p\cdot q$. Any other ideas?

Comment: I just followed the link in the comment on the other question you linked.  It is indeed probabilistic.  The attacker has to guess certain factors in a certain exponent and only then can they factor $N$.  I suggest you read and digest the link.

Answer (score 1):

A small $e$ is not an issue for factoring $N$, a relatively small $d$ is (this can be attacked by the continued fraction technique, or lattices). Typically in modern systems $e=2^{16}+1$ is quite common, as it's prime and has only two bits set, so makes for relatively fast encryption or signature checking. If both $e$ and $d$ are known, there is a fast probabilistic attack to factor $N$ (as you linked to). So $d$ really has to be kept secret (of course) and cannot be chosen conventiently small (for fast decryption, say); this would typically make $e$ large (and suspicious: $e$'s that are not small stand out, and are inefficient ) and attackers would probably break $d$ and thus $N$ and the system.. A small $e$ alone gets you no advantage...