# Simplifying modulo expression with large powers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I was wondering if there was a way to reduce the exponents in this expression, so that it can be calculated for very large value of exponent, in particular for large $y$ (i.e. $3000$).

$$(x^y+1)\bmod (y^x+1) = 0 $$

I want to find for which positive integers x and y this is true. For this reason, it is necessary to test very large numbers for $y$ and because of hardware limitations I need to find a way to reduce it beforehand, if it exists.

Using properties of the modulo operator does not bring me anywhere, and I do not see how I can reduce at least the first exponent. I could do something if I could prove that:

$$x^y\bmod a = x\bmod \sqrt[y]{a}$$

But I did not find anything similar so far.

EDIT: Since I need the modulo to be equal to zero, I can say that the first expression is equal to:
$$x^y-1=n \times (y^x+1)$$
where $n$ is a positive integer, and so:
$$x=\sqrt[y](n \times (y^x+1)-1)$$
I got rid of the large exponent $y$ but I have now to check for any value of $n$ (possibly extremely large) to evaluate the equation. If I could go back to the modulo operator from here it would be perfect.

Comment: There are ways to compute $x^y\!\!\mod m$ for large $y$, but they depend on tracking remainders of powers of $x$ modulo $m$, see [Modular exponentiation](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~mlazar/math170/notes06-3.pdf). Do not expect any general "formula". Expressions like $\sqrt[y]{a}$ do not make much sense in modular arithmetic.

Comment: I am aware of modular exponentiation, but I don't see how it can be applied to my case, which seems to be more complex, because of the $+c$ addition. Or is there a way to reduce my equation to the basic $x^y\ mod\ m$ case?

Comment: You are just computing $x^y\bmod (a^b+c)$, $c$ is a fixed value that can be added at the end. Although now you are talking about solving an equation, so I am not sure what the question is. Give an example with specific numbers, and which variable is solved for if this is an equation.

Comment: I disagree on “$c$ is a fixed value that can be added at the end”, @Conifold . After all, $a^b+c$ is what you’re dividing by. In particular, most ways of doing such calculation will use Chinese Remainder Theorem, which requires knowledge of the prime factorization of $a^b+c$. So OP should not expect a magical makes-it-easy solution to such a problem.

Comment: I updated, the first expression has to be equal to zero, that's what I meant. However, if I find for which value of $x,y$ the equation $x^y\ mod\ (a^b+c) =0$ I still have no information about my problem, which is $x^y+c\ mod\ (a^b+c) =0$

Comment: Are $x,y$ unknown and $a,b,c$ known? You want all pairs $x,y$ that solve this congruence?

Comment: Exactly, I only know that they are positive integers. $a,b$ can also be equal to $y,x$ and $c$ is a constant. I updated with a particular case, maybe like this it is clearer.

Comment: mod $a^b+c$ is equivalent to a shift in base $a$ by $b$ to the right and multiplying by $-c$ and adding that to the last $b$ digits base $a$  of the original value. @Lubin

Comment: @Conifold you weren't entirely correct.

Comment: In fact we can make @Lubin's comment more precise: let $\,n = a^b+c.\, $ Since calculating $\,\phi(n)\,$ is [(poly-time) equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12367/242) to factoring $\,n,\,$ any algorithm method that employs knowledge of $\,\phi(n)\,$ is at least as hard as factoring $\,n\ \ $

Comment: If you restrict yourself to $y=2$, the solutions are this sequence from OEIS: https://oeis.org/A247220 , which doesn't seem to have a formula yet.

Comment: Well, you’ve changed your question considerably. Now you’re just asking for pairs of numbers $(x,y)$ for which $(y^x+1)|(x^y+1)$. I rather wish you had submitted this as a separate question, since most of the comments above relate to your original question.

Comment: This is because I was looking for a way to reduce the exponents in the general case, I am not interested in asking for a specific solution to this problem. I want to find myself the pairs of numbers (and their series) which satisfy the equation, and I largely did. However, due to hardware limitations, I got stuck at a certain point, for very large values of $y$, this is why I was looking for method to reduce that expression.

Comment: @ACheca, I did find them for 2 myself, and indeed 2 is the only case where a sensical series cannot be found. For even numbers, in general, is necessary to test extremely large numbers to find something (there is a reasonable series for 6,10,14,18 etc, but not for 8,12,16 - thus the need to reduce the exponents). But the question is about how to simplify the exponents, not about how to find such pairs.