# Finding common factors in modulus in system of congruences

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I'm given three numbers $e,d_1,d_2\in \mathbb{N}$ where:
\begin{align}
e\cdot d_1 &\equiv 1 \pmod {(p-1)(q-1)}\\
e\cdot d_2 &\equiv 1 \pmod {(p-1)(r-1)}
\end{align}
Where $p,q,r$ are unknown primes.

Does there exist an efficient way of finding any of the primes?

My first though was calculating $(p-1)(q-1)=e\cdot d_1-1=n_1$ and $(p-1)(r-1)=e\cdot d_2-1=n_2$ and then finding $p=\gcd(n_1,n_2)+1$, but this obviously doesn't work since $p-1$ isn't prime.

Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: $ed_1 \equiv 1 \pmod {(p-1)(q-1)}$ doesn't mean that $(p-1)(q-1)=ed_1-1$, only that $(p-1)(q-1)$ divides $ed_1-1$. It's certainly true that $p-1$ must be a divisor of $\gcd(ed_1-1,ed_2-1)$, but I don't immediately see anything clever to do with that information other than guess-and-check. (Note that the answer won't necessarily be unique. For example, $p=2$ seems quite likely to work...!)

Comment: If also $pq$ was known, there exist polynomial-time algorithms to calculate $p$ and $q$. Discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12328/635667).